# Need to take two strings out of an URL using MVC. How is this done?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-parameters

I need to take the token and username out of a url to store as a variable in my code for MVC. The URL is

```
local.test.test.com/Login/PasswordReset?u=test.hitt@emp.test.com&t=5cd5acc2-2446-47fb-862d-7a13871aa523
```

The username would be: test.hitt@emp.test.com
The token being: 5cd5acc2-2446-47fb-862d-7a13871aa523

I currently have what is below, but am getting a null value.

```
 string userName = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["u"]);
 string userToken = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["t"]);
```

Comment: In MVC these would be parameters on your controller's action method.

Answer (score 0):

They should be set at parameters on the controller action. And then can be set in a model to return to the view or alternatively you could use the viewbag if you  are so inclined.

```
public ActionResult PasswordReset(string u, Guid t)
{
    // put u and t into a view model to send to the view

   var model = new PasswordResetModel(u, t);

    return View(model);
}
```